what versions of kie and kie spring to be used in my application with drool version .44.2.final and jdk17
My application has spring-boot-starter-parent 2.7.18, drool versions 7.73.0.final , kie-api and kie spring api also 7.73.0.final and java version 17.  I want to upgrage my droolversion to 8.44.2.Final so what versions of kie and kie spring to be used?Also specific drool config file code as in my config file i am using org.kie.internal.io.ResourceFactory and org.kie.spring.KModuleBeanFactoryPostProcessor.
i have tried different combinations of kie spring and droom but facing many issues related to compatibility as kie spring dont have 8.xx versions available. my requirement is to make drool version in 8.xx .
i have tried 7.44..final version of kie spring. removed KModuleBeanFactoryProcessor related code.still got error saying unable to instantiate kiecontainer, kiesession
